# Почему работает функция JavaScript

Tags: javascript, анимация

Почему этот код работает?
Вот какая я думаю, почему он работает:
1) Переменные все сохраняются и срабатывает вызов функции `gameEngineStart(gameLoopRight)`
2) Выполняются тело функции `gameEngineStart` -> 
`gameEngine` = телу функции `gameLoopRight`, потом срабытывает вызов функции `gameEngineStep()`
3) Выполняется функция `gameEngineStep` ->
вызывается `reqAnimFrame(gameEngineStep)`, `reqAnimFrame` становится ссылкой на функцию `requestAnimationFrame`, если всё хорошо, иначе возвращается название функции для нужного браузера, а потом уже обычный `setTimeout`
`reqAnimFrame` вызывается с аргументом `gameEngineStep`, который должен был вызвать саму себя(по логике) и так бесконечно. Но дальше происходит срабатывание `gameEngine()`
Дальше всё понятно как работает, но вот этот момент непонятен, почему функция не вызывает саму себя бесконечно, а может выполнить вызов `gameEngine()`?

```js
var gameEngine;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 10, y = 10;

function drawRect() {
 context.fillStyle = 'black';
 context.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
 context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}

var reqAnimFrame = (function() {
 return requestAnimationFrame       ||
        mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
 function (callback) {
     setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
})();

function gameEngineStart(callback) {
 gameEngine = callback;
 gameEngineStep();
}

function gameEngineStep() {
 reqAnimFrame(gameEngineStep);
 gameEngine();
}

function setGameEngine(callback) {
 gameEngine = callback;
}

function gameLoopRight() {
 drawRect();
 x += 2;
 if (x >= 240) {
  setGameEngine(gameLoopLeft);
 }
}

function gameLoopLeft() {
 drawRect();
 x -= 2;
 if (x < 20) {
  setGameEngine(gameLoopRight);
 }
}

gameEngineStart(gameLoopRight);
```

```css
#canvas {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="70px"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я точно не понял полностью как работает `requestAnimationFrame`, но при выводе в консоль сообщения из функции `gameEngineStep`, оно выводилось 60 раз в секунду. Я пытался тоже самое проделать(вызвать саму себя функцией, без таймеров), но без `requestAnimationFrame`, в итоге всё глючило и браузер не отвечал. 
`requestAnimationFrame` работает так, что она не нагрузит процессор, если вызывать функцию рекурсивно, она будет вызываться только 60 раз в секудну(обычно, зависит от монитора).
Мне не нравится, что `requestAnimationFrame` (я так думаю, возможно это неправильно) срабатывает больше раз, чем необходимо для отрисовки, т.е. некоторые вызовы функции происходят просто так. В будущем планирую разобраться, как это работает, когда пойму

Comment: вы действительно не поняли, как это работает

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @ThisMan я весь гугл и яндекс читал несколько раз об этом, но всё равно не понял) Эту страницу я открывал около 15 раз, и на javascript.ru тоже много раз

Comment: грубо говоря внутри браузера есть цикл, которые выполняется 60 раз в секунду, в конце каждого цикла браузер рисует страницу, а перед самой отрисовкой выполняет callback, которые передали в `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: @ThisMan так чуть понятнее, спасибо

Answer (score -2):

примерно ваша цитата: а потом уже обычный таймаут с вечным циклом.

как работает таймаут? вызывается, запоминает что ему ныжно выпольнить что-то там черзе какое то время. и все. вышел из функции. и пошел работать код дальше:

```
function gameEngineStep() {
    reqAnimFrame(gameEngineStep);
    gameEngine();
}
```

а дальше - gameEngine()
Вот, а когда пройдет положенное время внезапно в параллельном процессе исполнится то что запомнил сетТаймаут. В параллельном! И помните, каждый вызов сетТаймаут дает именно параллельный процесс.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. `setTimeout` вызовется только, если все версии браузеров не поддерживаются для `requestAnimationFrame`. Как я предополагаю, у меня ОЧЕНБ-ОЧЕНЬ часто вызывается `gameEngineStep`, а с ним ещё параллельно все функции `gameEngineStep`, которые смогли вызваться и по факту, это должно быть очень плохо. Но анимация не дрожит и не ходит ходуном, но она же должна пускаться в пляс, если так много вызывается

Comment: В js нет паралелльных процессов. Точнее, они есть, но пользовательский код в них не выполняется.